# Sealing flammability standard

Tags: power-electronics, environmental-sealing

I have a part which has 4 pins(2 of them power pins and rest is control pins). Should I use UL94 conformed sealing or sealant without flammability property is also OK? Max  working current: 220mA, Max Short Current can be 1.5A as the battery provides this. These pins are inside of a closed area.[image]

Comment: You don't really provide enough context to allow the question to be answered.  If this was for a cheap kids radio it probably doesn't matter, if it is for a key control circuit on a nuclear reactor or to be used in an explosive environment you might have some very specific requirements...

Comment: I need it for a sensor thats works in a humid and wet area.